# org.mule.module.client.MuleClient not found compile error

Tags: compiler-errors, mule, anypoint-studio

I have a Mule project that generates the following compile error:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /G:/git/edx-client-service/edx_client/src/test/java/test/RestTestBase.java:[21,30] package org.mule.module.client does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.633 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-18T15:23:08-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project edx_client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /G:/git/edx-client-service/edx_client/src/test/java/test/RestTestBase.java:[21,30] package org.mule.module.client does not exist
```

I have tried to exclude test package in my pom.xml file to get around this issue:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/src/test/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This does not work. I have googled for any ideas to no avail. Any ideas what I need to do or look next?

Comment: Clean build all your projects in the eclipse. This might help

Comment: I did try this as I have had this work for me in other projects. I still had the same problem. Adding the mule-module-client dependency did the trick.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't have "org.mule.module.client" on your maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This did worked for me. I had some Javadoc errors as a result of the strict rules of JDK 8, but temporarily bypassed those by turning off doclint.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that dependency to your project, but probably you will need other Mule dependencies too, so a good solution would be to add the distribution dependency with test scope (this way it won't be included in your packaged app): org.mule.distributions: mule-standalone:3.7.0:tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the dependency from your POM file and then download the requried JAR file from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule/mule-core/3.7.0 .Do not forget to add it to your buildpath.